# I run gclient sync and build chromium source ,and get a error ,follow

Tags: chromium

[image]

> '['D:\Download\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe',
>   'D:\Download\depot_tools\win_toolchain\get_toolchain_if_necessary.py',
>   '--output-json',
>   'D:\Download\chromium\src\build\win_toolchain.json',
>   '95ddda401ec5678f15eeed01d2bee08fcbc5ee97']' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1 Error: Command
>   'D:\Download\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe
>   src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in
>   D:\Download\chromium

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem.
In my case, gl clien
Please check your cmd mode (It should be admin mode).